# How to do I alter code so chart will display?

Tags: vega-lite

I have created an interactive sorted bar chart using an online vega lite editor (https://vega.github.io/editor/#) however my chart will not display despite running through each line and checking syntax. Need some help please!

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dkeeley/dkeeley/master/Happiness_2019.csv",
    "format": {
      "type": "csv"
    }
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "filter": "datum.Score > 0"
   },
   {
      "filter": "datum.GDP_per_capita > 0"
    },
    {
      "filter": "indexof(datum.Country_or_region, ',') > 0"
    }
  ],  
 "repeat": {"column": ["Score","GDP_per_capita"]},
 "spec":{
    "selection": {
        "Country_or_region_selection": {"type": "multi", "fields": ["Country_or_region"]}
      },
    "mark": "bar",
    "encoding": {
        "y": {
        "field": "Country_or_region",
        "type": "nominal",
        "axis": {"title": null},
        "sort": {
            "op": "sum",
            "field": {"repeat": "column"},
            "order": "descending"
        }
        },
        "x": {
        "field": {"repeat": "column"},
        "type": "quantitative",
        "aggregate": "sum"
        },
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "selection": "Country_or_region_selection",
            "field": "Country_or_region",
            "type":"nominal",
            "legend":null
            },
          "value": "grey"    
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data is a `"tsv"` rather than a `"csv"`, and your fields have spaces rather than underscores (i.e. `datum['Country or region']`, not `datum.Country_or_region`):

([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAMyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtBmx5CBbUgDu1OoyYMIcbVDmY4szJUcICygNZw4guABPL19-IIJkCGdtAgAJJBwcGlk4CAgAfQAmAAYARgBOdwhiRRAAMzZtZEw0UExAnDh9TGKQAF82pUxTWQgKqrQAbVAymkFo-VVMBgRKAGVHbTgAAgA+Zez2hRGxifQpmcGAcgBxABEABWXG7WWoBLokI4BdNY3256UlxrVakEdBDN5KhBiAFpUmkpzlcbncHuoQM9OiAII0oH87AEoJh2MDQABhNgMVzaQLpSrpJa0OTpTFwbG4v71Rr6BAMcY0UqjfzKCBDECE4ndQLLSrLKmMpHI5Dabz6JhIbSlFyOZTJMh-QJ-bmCZT6QUkkViiVyUrMproWRsBDJJB6JRIAAeND5mhAOMwATQsnZgmRMm0NTdbBw+ggMy5NB5f2+cF+6ABQK2IEqynsk1SUBcatkGo6Skd2qjupjcB+Qf+bEBCHkyPN+gAjgwkK5HjjSKUkGQyFS1BaURHkQDKn9HLI1TjTW66QypwKiYbydpKeRcbSwrP5EodXr0AbhaLbiat+6Gv2rTbZHbSgEyNnvb7kcQ7Qx+z2gu0Om0gA))

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dkeeley/dkeeley/master/Happiness_2019.csv",
    "format": {
      "type": "tsv"
    }
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "filter": "datum.Score > 0"
   },
   {
      "filter": "datum['GDP per capita'] > 0"
    }
  ],  
 "repeat": {"column": ["Score","GDP per capita"]},
 "spec":{
    "selection": {
        "Country_or_region_selection": {"type": "multi", "fields": ["Country or region"]}
      },
    "mark": "bar",
    "encoding": {
        "y": {
        "field": "Country or region",
        "type": "nominal",
        "axis": {"title": null},
        "sort": {
            "op": "sum",
            "field": {"repeat": "column"},
            "order": "descending"
        }
        },
        "x": {
        "field": {"repeat": "column"},
        "type": "quantitative",
        "aggregate": "sum"
        },
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "selection": "Country_or_region_selection",
            "field": "Country or region",
            "type":"nominal",
            "legend":null
            },
          "value": "grey"    
        }
    }
  }
}
```